# Erro na conexão Java com Banco de Dados MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Estou fazendo uma conexão de uma aplicação Java com um Banco de Dados SQL, tenho o seguinte código de conexão:

**ConnectionFactory.java:**

```
package connection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionFactory {
    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbloja";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASS = "****************";

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);            
            return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro na conexao", ex);
        }
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con) {
        if(con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex);                        
            }
        }
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt) {
        if(stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex);  
            }
        }

        closeConnection(con);
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt, ResultSet rs) {
        if(rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex);  
            }
        }

        closeConnection(con, stmt);
    }
}
```

**CategoriaDAO.java:**

```
package model.dao;

import connection.ConnectionFactory;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import model.bean.Categoria;

/**
 *
 * @author Vinicius Souza
 */
public class CategoriaDAO {
    private Connection con = null;

    public CategoriaDAO() {
        con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    }

    public boolean save(Categoria categoria){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO categoria (descricao) VALUES (?)";

        PreparedStatement stmt = null;        

        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, categoria.getDescricao());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex);
            return false;
        } finally {
            ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, stmt);
        }
    }

}
```

**CategoriaDAOTest.java**

```
package model.dao;

import model.bean.Categoria;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Vinicius Souza
 */
public class CategoriaDAOTest {

    public CategoriaDAOTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void inserir() {

        Categoria cat = new Categoria("Roupas");
        CategoriaDAO dao = new CategoriaDAO();

        if(dao.save(cat)) {
            System.out.println("Saved");
        } else {
            fail("Error saving");
        }
    }

}
```

Porém, estou recebendo esse erro:

```
Testcase: inserir(model.dao.CategoriaDAOTest):  Caused an ERROR
Erro na conexao
java.lang.RuntimeException: Erro na conexao
    at connection.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:21)
    at model.dao.CategoriaDAO.<init>(CategoriaDAO.java:17)
    at model.dao.CategoriaDAOTest.inserir(CategoriaDAOTest.java:20)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1725)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at connection.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:18)
```

Creio que seja um erro na passagem da password, porém não sei como arrumar isso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Qual a versão do mysql_connector que está utilizando ?

Comment: @ViktorHugo estou usando o mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar

Comment: Cara a única solução que consegui para te ajudar seria criar um novo usuário sem o **caching_sha2_password**:

`CREATE USER '<seu-usuario>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<sua-senha>'; `

Assim você terá um usuário da forma antiga do MySQL

Answer (score -2):

Vinicius Souza,

Creio eu que o problema esteja no driver do jdbc do seu mysql, tente usar o driver em outra versão.

Abç.